# In VBA, what is the syntax for writing a formula relative to a range?

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel, I've written a short script that should remove the first character of each cell containing a "*"symbol at the start of it. What I have so far is

```
Sub Macro5()

Dim Rng As Range
Dim i As Long
i = 1

While i <= 20000
Set Rng = Range("A" & i)

    If InStr(Rng, "*") > 0 Then
        Rng.Offset(0, 1).Formula = "=Right(Rng,LEN(Rng)-1)"
        i = i + 1
    Else: i = i + 1

End If
Wend
End Sub
```

The line to call the script seems to work, but the formula getting placed into column B is "=Right(Rng,LEN(Rng)-1)", which gives a 'NAME?' error. How do I define the LEN formula to use Rng as a range, rather than as a 'word' on the spreadsheet?

Comment: not tested, but try changing it to: "=Right(" & Rng & ",LEN(" & Rng & ")-1)"

Comment: Change `"=Right(Rng,LEN(Rng)-1)"` to `"=Right(" & Rng.address(0,0) & ",LEN(" & Rng.address(0,0) & ")-1)"`  Vba needs to be on the outside of the quotes.

Comment: Awesome. I knew it would be something simple. Much appreciated! :)

Comment: @sous2817 that will put the value in the formula not the address.  this may be what the OP wants but if that is the case it needs to be surrounded by quotes when the formula is placed so Excel knows it is a string.  Right now if rng.value is `start` then the formula placed will be `=Right(start,LEN(start)-1)` when it should be `=Right("start",LEN("start")-1)`

Comment: @ScottCraner doh!  that's what I get for drive-by comments and not testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `R1C1 type formulae` makes life much easier in that situation.

```
Sub RemoveFirstStar()
    Dim rng As Range, c As Range

    Set rng = Range("A1:A2000")

    For Each c In rng.Cells
        If Left(c, 1) = "*" Then
            c.Offset(0, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=mid(rc[-1],2,1000)"
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

For your particular code example, change the line after the `IF`:

```
Rng.Offset(0, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=Right(RC[-1],LEN(RC[-1])-1)"
```